# How to convert Map to Json using Json4s

Tags: json, scala, json4s

I am using the json4s library to convert maps in scala to json but keep running into a basic error when operating on Map[Char,Int]:

Here is the code sample that is giving me problems.

```
  import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
  import org.json4s.JsonDSL.WithDouble._

    val myMap = Map('a' -> 123)

    render(myMap)
```

error: No implicit view available from (Char, Int) => org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue.

> Question:  What is the correct way to convert a Map that is made of [Char, Int] to a Json object using Json4s?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The keys of a JSON object are always strings, and furthermore, there is no equivalent of `Char` in JSON. See [json.org](http://json.org) for the specification.

You could convert the keys of your `Map[Char, Int]` before rendering:

```
myMap.map { case(k, v) => (k.toString, v) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you could consider to use

``println(scala.util.parsing.json.JSONObject(m))```

From Scala 2.10